# Vocal range of songs

Tags: vocal-range

I'm not aware that it's normal to include vocal ranges in songs' sheet music. The key and tempo are usually included, but, judging by the amount of 'what am I, tenor, baritone, etc' question on this site, I feel an included range of notes (or tessitura) would be invaluable.

Would it be a useful addition to songs for many (any) singers? It might help singers who know their  range, to be able to leave a song as is, or know where to modulate it to.

Comment: I'm confused. "I'm not aware that it's normal to include vocal ranges in songs' sheet music." The range of every part, vocal or otherwise, **is** included in the sheet music for the part.

Comment: @ToddWilcoxthanks for the immediate dv! I meant that the range for the main vocal in a song could be included, without having to trawl through the entire song to find the highest/lowest notes. As in C3>F4. See Laurence's answer. Not difficult to understand.

Comment: I guess what I don't understand is why "trawl through an entire song" isn't the first thing everyone does when they first look at a piece of music. Personally it takes me seconds to determine the range of a part that is 4 or fewer pages, as most songs seem to be.

Comment: @ToddWilcox  it's just not what I expect most people to do. Maybe, like you do, they do, but I've never noticed it. Sing through, and then decide it's out of range, yes.

Comment: Tim - please don't add an additional question into an already closed one. It would make it less suitable for reopening, as it would have multiple questions in one post.

Comment: @DoktorMayhem - I was asked to edit this question to be re-opened. I thought that's what I did, to elucidate on the original, which wasn't well understood. No point at all in adding any extra questions, as it seemed necessary to clarify the original better.

Comment: Any chance you can try and reword the question that already existed - it looked like the additional paragraph you added was a new question, so maybe just needs to be a bit clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as a classic 'opinion' question, I don't suppose this one will survive long!   But, yes, I think it could be useful.

It sometimes is/was done.  Particularly when a song was offered in a choice of keys for different voice types.  And it's common to give the range of each character in Music Theatre scores.

[image: Brown Bird song copy]

Comment: +1, and accepted. I do seem to remember, in the dim and distant past, songs having that note at the top of the song, but haven't seen it for decades. Just felt it might be a good idea again.